# programmatically close Android settings after event has occured

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, settings

So I created an app that connects to a wireless display on Android automatically for the user. The easiest way I found to do that is by opening the Screen Mirroring settings. This makes it easier for the user, so they don't have to go up to settings and enable it themselves.

Now that I have connected to the display, I want the Screen Mirroring screen to go away and return to the app or to the home screen if the user wants.

Here is the code I use to open Screen Mirroring settings to connect the user to the display after he clicks on a button:

```
try 
{
    activityint = 1;
    Log.d("DEBUG", "open WiFi display settings in HTC");
    startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.htc.wifidisplay.CONFIGURE_MODE_NORMAL"),activityint);
} catch (Exception e) 
{
    try 
    {
        activityint = 2;
        Log.d("DEBUG", "open WiFi display settings in Samsung");
        startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.samsung.wfd.LAUNCH_WFD_PICKER_DLG"),activityint);
    }catch (Exception e2) 
    {
        activityint=3;
        Log.d("DEBUG", "open WiFi display settings in stock Android");
        startActivityForResult(new Intent("android.settings.WIFI_DISPLAY_SETTINGS"),activityint);
    }
}
```

And then I have a broadcastreceiver that listens for WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION. When this happens, it will look to see if we are now connected before launching other things and then attempting to close the settings activity.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION)) 
    {
        /**
        * What to do if the P2P connection has changed
        */
        try
        {
            NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if(info!=null && info.isConnected())
            {

                connected(true);
                //Kill the settings activity
                finishActivity(activityint);

            }else if(info!=null && !info.isConnected())
            {
                connected(false);
            }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("DEBUG", "exception", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that it kills the settings activity before the connection is finalized. So it will back out of the settings activity and the Screen Mirroring connection will cancel a moment before it connects. Is there a better way or a different way to be able to back out of the Settings activity? Or am I listening for the wrong intent in my receiver?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The only way I was able to close a settings page on some event, is to start my activity again with the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag.

This way, because your activity is the one that opened the settings activity, the flag will make the system finish it. To the user it will appear that the settings activity just went away.

Answer (score -1):

I guess I'm answering my own questions. I found this code that allows me to send a delayed response. I know this is crummy programming because some devices will finish before others, but this works for me at the moment. If anyone knows of a better way, please feel free to let me know.

This goes in my broadcast receiver's onReceive method.

```
NetworkInfo info = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
if(info!=null && info.isConnected())
{

    connected(true);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() 
    { 
        public void run() 
        { 
            finishActivity(activityint);
        } 
    }, 5000); 


}else if(info!=null && !info.isConnected())
{
    connected(false);
}
```

EDIT: This actually does not work for me. After testing further, I found that it will kick me back to the home screen after a few moments even when I just open the app. It's pretty annoying. Anyone know of a better idea?